# where i passed the follow int s to show my report.... coz it give me error Sp_Invoice_Detail' expects parameter '@SaleID', which was not supplied

Tags: c#

my code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-C8H8UQI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IMSDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
ReportDocument rprt = new ReportDocument();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_Invoice_Detail", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds, "item,invoice,sale");
rprt.Load(@"C:\Users\Zia Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\lol\lol\Report\finalreport.rpt");

        rprt.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rprt;
```

this query is used to grab the last sale id from sale table

```
string query4 = "select isnull(max(cast(SaleID as int)), 0) +0 from sale";
            SqlDataAdapter sda4 = new SqlDataAdapter(query4, con);
            DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
            sda4.Fill(dt4);
            int s = Convert.ToInt32(dt4.Rows[0][0]);
```

while store procedure is

```
Create Proc Sp_Invoice_Detail

    @SaleID int
    as 
    begin
    Select Item.Barcode , Item.ItemName as item, Item.SalePrice as price, invoice.Qty, invoice.Disc FROM invoice JOIN item ON invoice.ItemID = item.ItemID where SaleID=@SaleID;
```

end

Comment: Can you point us to your line of code where you supplied the value for parameter @SaleID?

Comment: actually i don't where to pass this int s

Comment: And we have to pass this parameter to next line of cmd.commandtype.....